# Java 21 ObjectMapper not working with Records

Tags: java, jackson, java-record, java-21

I am using Java 21, and trying to convert a String from a REST response to a record. However, I am getting an error:

```
org.testcontainers.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.myapp.model.MyRecord: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

I know it will work when I add:

```
@JsonProperty("...")
```

for every field, but is there any way to convert the String with ObjectMapper without having to add the @JsonProperty annotation?

Comment: Is it intended you use the Jackson version shaded by testcontainers instead of directly a Jackson version you own? In both cases, which Jackson version is it?

Comment: Jackson 2.12+ (I think?) supports Java records.

Comment: @GaëlJ That was it! Thank you. It was not intended to use the testcontainers Jackson, I must have imported that one instead on accident. Thanks again!